# How do I read a file and store it as a Matrix (2D aray)?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, filestream, readfile

I have a graph coloring program that takes in a 2D array as an adjacency matrix and colors the graph based on that adjacency matrix.  This file is `Color.cpp`. I have another program that creates this adjacency matrix and puts it in a text file, this program `AdjacencyMatrix.cpp`.

When I originally created the coloring program, I hard coded the adjacency matrix into the 2D array `graph[V][V]` where V is the number of vertices.

These are two separate programs, I was just copying and pasting the adjacency matrix created by `AdjacencyMatrix.cpp` into `Color.cpp`.

Because my program already creates a file with the adjacency matrix in it, I want to have my coloring program read that file.  I know best practice is to combine them and have the matrix stored in the array passed into the coloring program in one cohesive program. I think reading a file is my simplest solution at this point, but if more experienced users can show me how to store the matrix in a data structure and pass it into the coloring program, I welcome it.

**AdjacencyMatrix.cpp**

This program takes in a file that is a string of integers listed as adjacent pairs and creates an adjacency matrix from it, then stores it in a file.  The file "24cell_skeleton.txt" is the file it reads in and "out.txt" is the file it prints the matrix into.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
const int cellSize = 24;
bool graph[cellSize][cellSize];
int prevNum = -1;
int currNum = -1;


bool markMatrix(int x, int y) {
graph[x][y] = true;
graph[y][x] = true;
/*std:cout << "adding pair: " << y << "," << x << "\n";*/
return true;

}

int main()
{

ifstream in("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Documents\\adjMatrix\\24cell_skeleton.txt");
ofstream out;
out.open("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Documents\\adjMatrix\\output.txt", ios::out);
ios::out;

string line, field;

vector< vector<string> > array;  // the 2D array
vector<string> v;                // array of values for one line only

while (getline(in, line))    // get next line in file
{
    v.clear();
    stringstream ss(line);

    while (getline(ss, field, ','))  // break line into comma delimited fields
    {
        v.push_back(field);  // add each field to the 1D array
    }

    array.push_back(v);  // add the 1D array to the 2D array
}

// print out what was read in
bool firstIter = true;

for (size_t i = 0; i<array.size(); ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j<array[i].size(); ++j)
    {
        string curr = array[i][j]; // (separate fields by |)
        prevNum = currNum;
        currNum = stoi(curr);

        if (j != 0 && firstIter) { //if its not the first iteration . . . or the last?
                                   /*out << "adding pair: " << prevNum << "," << currNum << "\n";*/
            markMatrix(prevNum, currNum);
        }
    }
    firstIter = false;

}

in.close();


//std::cout << "{";
for (int i = 1; i <= cellSize; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "{";
    out << "{";
    for (int j = 1; j <= cellSize; ++j)
    {
        //std::cout << "{";
        std::cout << graph[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << ", ";
        out << graph[i][j] << ' ';
        out << ", ";
        //std::cout << "}";
    }
    out << "},";
    std::cout << "},";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

//std::cout << "}";

out.close();
//cout << graph[534][42];

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

**Color.cpp**

This file colors a graph given an adjacency matrix. Like I mentioned before, the matrix is hard coded into it (copy and pasted from the file the previous program created). This is where I would like to read the file instead of copy and paste it myself.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdio>


// Number of vertices in the graph
#define V 24

using namespace std;

//this function was added in the update to attempt reading file and storing into a 2d matrix

int createMatrix(int myArray[V][V]) 
{
  ifstream in("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Documents\\adjMatrix\\output.txt");

  for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < V; j++)
    {
        in >> myArray[i][j];
    }
  }
return myArray[V][V];
}
//end of updated code added

void printSolution(int color[]);

/* A utility function to check if the current color assignment
is safe for vertex v */
bool isSafe(int v, bool graph[V][V], int color[], int c)
{
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    if (graph[v][i] && c == color[i])
        return false;
return true;
}

/* A recursive utility function to solve m coloring problem */
bool graphColoringUtil(bool graph[V][V], int m, int color[], int v)
{
/* base case: If all vertices are assigned a color then
return true */
if (v == V)
    return true;

/* Consider this vertex v and try different colors */
for (int c = 1; c <= m; c++)
{
    /* Check if assignment of color c to v is fine*/
    if (isSafe(v, graph, color, c))
    {
        color[v] = c;

        /* recur to assign colors to rest of the vertices */
        if (graphColoringUtil(graph, m, color, v + 1) == true)
            return true;

        /* If assigning color c doesn't lead to a solution
        then remove it */
        color[v] = 0;
    }
}

/* If no color can be assigned to this vertex then return false */
return false;
}

bool graphColoring(bool graph[V][V], int m)
{
// Initialize all color values as 0. This initialization is needed
// correct functioning of isSafe()
int *color = new int[V];
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    color[i] = 0;

// Call graphColoringUtil() for vertex 0
if (graphColoringUtil(graph, m, color, 0) == false)
{
    std::cout << "Solution does not exist";
    return false;
}

// Print the solution
printSolution(color);
return true;
}

/* A utility function to print solution */
void printSolution(int color[])
{
std::cout << "Solution Exists:"
    " Following are the assigned colors \n";
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    std::cout << color[i];
std::cout << "\n";
}

// driver program to test above function
int main()
{

/* Create following graph and test whether it is 3 colorable
(3)---(2)
| / |
| / |
| / |
(0)---(1)
*/
bool graph[V][V] = {
    { 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , },
    { 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , },
    { 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , },
    { 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , },
    { 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , },
    { 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , },
    { 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , },
    { 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , },
    { 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , },
    { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , },
    { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , },
    { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , },
    { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , },
    { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , },
    { 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , },
};
int m = 5; // Number of colors
graphColoring(graph, m);
//return 0;

system("pause");
}
```

**Is there a way to take in this matrix from the file rather than hard coding it into the program?**  The brackets and commas are easy to add or remove from the file.  They are necessary when hard coded into the coloring program but I don't think they would be necessary if I could read from the file.

To make this as clear as possible, where you see the 24x24 matrix in `Color.cpp`, I would like to have that section be a matrix read from out.txt that `AdjacencyMatrix.cpp` creates.

**Edit/Update**

I have this so far in the beginning of `color.cpp`

```
int createMatrix(int myArray[V][V]) 
{
  ifstream in("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Documents\\adjMatrix\\output.txt");

  for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < V; j++)
    {
        in >> myArray[i][j];
    }
  }
return myArray[V][V];
}
```

I know something is off here, but if I can get this to work I plan to use something like

```
bool graph[V][V] = 
{ 
    myArray[V][V]
};
```

in `main()`.

As of now VisualStudio says `myArray` is an undeclared identifier and is undefined in `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there with your `createMatrix` function, but `return myArray[V][V];` not what you want to do. This is saying return a single  `int` that is outside the bounds of the array(Array of size V is valid 0 to V-1. [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) badness will result from breaching the array's bounds.

Fortunately you don't have to return a darn thing. `myArray` is a pointer to the array that `createMatrix` was called with (See [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)) so `in >> myArray[i][j];` is reading the file directly into the array.

So with a few checks to make sure the reading succeeded:

```
bool createMatrix(int myArray[V][V]) 
{
    ifstream in("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Documents\\adjMatrix\\output.txt");
    if (in) // if the file is open and readable
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < V; j++)
            {
                if (!(in >> myArray[i][j]))
                { // failed to read a value from the file. Bad file
                    // may want to log the error here so you know why it failed
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    { // couldn't open the file
        // may want to log the error here so you know why it failed
        return false;
    }
    return true; // read everything we wanted to read. all done.
}
```

and then in `main`

```
int main()
{
    int graph[V][V];
    if (createMatrix(graph)) 
    { // read the file successfully
        int m = 5; // Number of colors
        graphColoring(graph, m);
    }
    else
    { // did not read the file successfully
         // display failure message
    }
    system("pause");
}
```